# Sequential Search inside of array issue

Tags: c#, arrays, sequential

```
    string[] names = { "Abby", "Bill", "Connie", "David", "Eddy" };

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear the array labels

        array1Label.Text = "";
        array2Label.Text = "";
    }

    private void passArrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Demo how to pass an array
        //Which really means passing the reference vairable to the array.

        //Create an array

        int[] array1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

        //Pass array1 to a method to double and dsiplay the array

        DoubleArray(array1);

    }

    private void DoubleArray(int[] theArray1)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < theArray1.Length; x++)
        {
            theArray1[x] = theArray1[x] * 2;
        }

        //display the array

        foreach(int element in theArray1)
        {
            output = output + element + "\n";
        }

        array1Label.Text = output;

    }

    private void showNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        string[] names = { "Abby", "Bill", "Connie", "David", "Eddy" };           
    }     
}
```

Deeply confused on how to use a sequential search to be able to output "David" onto a label please help. This is my entire program the first part is just multiply all the numbers. Please help! There is no outside input just need to go through the "names" array and pick out "David" and output text into a label.

Comment: Are you looking for `MyLabel.Text = names.Contains("David") ? "David" : "";`?

Comment: Side note: `array1Label.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, theArray1);` is a better choice that your *foreach loop*

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
private void showNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchKey ="David";
    string output = "";
    string[] names = { "Abby", "Bill", "Connie", "David", "Eddy"};
    foreach(var name in names)
    {
       if(name == searchKey){
           output = name;
           break;
        }
    }
    array1Label.Text = output;
}
```

put anything in searchkey to find other than David.